# Can Adobe Air track other windows?

Tags: air

Can Adobe Air be used to track other windows? I want to build an application that tracks how long certain windows have been open. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

I'm just going to give you the blunt answer: No.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to take advantage of native processes in AIR. If a process could track of what you want and report to your AIR app, this might be possible. By reporting I mean your AIR app will trigger the native process you'll deploy with your package.